# how do I access linux machines by name on the network?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns

I run a home office and I have a number of linux boxes and mac machines. I'd like for people to be able to ssh into the various machines without having to remember each machines ip, by using the machine name. I realize that I could have everyone edit their hosts file, but I am looking for a better alternative than that. What tool, if any, exists for managing machine names and ips? Should I run my own internal DNS server?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Try using hostname.local. For instance, if your desktop is called petersdesk, then connect to petersdesk.local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it makes the most sense to use an internal DNS server.  It's a pretty common network service, and for what you're trying to accomplish, it's the perfect use.

Here's a tutorial from Digital Ocean for Ubuntu 14.04, it should work for the majority of ubuntu versions.

[How To Configure BIND as a Private Network DNS Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Pick one of the systems, set up `dnsmasq` (see `man dnsmasq`), Edit `/etc/hosts` on that system, restart `dnsmasq`, tell the others to resolve DNS through the picked system.

Comment: This is the easier solution for a small network.